# Add centered text within two regions

Tags: imagemagick

I have a picture in which I need to create some text. 
There are two regions where the text should appear. I was able to make these regions visible with the following code:

```
convert -verbose -pointsize 24 -font 'Arial' \
-region 200x60+90+60 -colorize 1% \
-fill white -draw "text 0,0 'Text 1'" \
+region \
-fill -region 275x35+10+10 -colorize 1% \
-fill black -draw "text 0,0 'another text'" \
+region \
${TEMPLATES_PATH}/base.bmp ${TEMPLATES_PATH}/result.bmp
```

[image: result of the first code snippet]

But unfortunately I am not able to add text to this regions. 
I tried several combinations of `-background` and `-fill`. My best guess is that the background of the region is now the same as the fill of the text. But I don't know how to change this.

```
convert -verbose -pointsize 24 -font 'Arial' \
-background black -region 200x60+90+60  \
-fill white -gravity center -draw "text 0,0 'Text 1'" \
+region \
-background white -region 275x35+10+10  \
-fill black -gravity center -draw "text 0,0 'another'" \
+region \
${TEMPLATES_PATH}/base.bmp ${TEMPLATES_PATH}/result.bmp
```

Results only in this:

[image]

Comment: I am not sure what the included image is supposed to show? Can you show the starting image and the expected result please?

Comment: I have a feeling you are using -region incorrectly; I think region is for say making the area within the region greyscale. Personally I would use -annotate to add text to the image -pointsize 24 -font Arial -annotate +50+20 'Text 1'

Comment: -draw does not respect gravity. So you have to compute the placements relative to the top left corner of the whole image. Bonzo is correct. You would be better to use -annotate, since it does respect gravity.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I did now split up the generation of the image. I first create two images and then I use `composite` to combine them.